# Simultaneous file reading

Tags: python, csv

I would like to do some basic maths in python. I have 2 csv files each with some junk data and some numerical data. I already created a porgram to strip the useful numerical data from a csv file and print it.

Now i need my code to access 2 csv files at the same time each to grab 1 ilne of data, then strip it down to numerical data then to set that as a variable so i can go ahead and do some maths then lastly write the answer of the maths problem into a 3rd file.

Here is how the file **shoud** look

```
while true:
    read file a - set data as int(a1)
    read file b - set data as int(b1)
    if a2 == 0 or b2 == 0:
         break
    else
    a2 - a1 = a3
    b2 - b1 = b3
    a2 / 100 = a4
    b2 / 100 = b4
    a3 / av = a5
    b3 / av = b5
    time.sellp(1)
    a1 = a2
    b1 = b2
    write file c- a5, b5
```

so basically im trying the % change between 2 sets of data and write them side by side in the same file. I could do this manually but this is for work and needs to happen on the fly and with over 10k lines of data.

so far i have the following code which strips data from 1 file and prints it in console.

```
import sys
import time
from sys import argv
argv1 = "Ard.csv"
script, filename = argv, argv1
a = open(filename, 'r')

while True:
    for i, linea in enumerate(a):
        abc1a =  (linea)[36:-10:]
        abc2a = float(abc1a)
        abc3a = int(abc2a)
        Ard = abc3a
        print (Ard)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Most of this i can figure out by myself, especialy the maths part. i only need help reading 2 files at the same time so i can compare the data. This is really important to my work and i am spending my weekend doing this so please help.

Thanks.

EDIT: Working code for others to reference - http://pastebin.com/H25XEXuu

Comment: If you have solved your problem, post it as an answer, rather than linking to an off-site resource that may disappear at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
import itertools

with open('fileA.csv') as fa:
    with open('fileB.csv') as fb:
        for (i, (la, lb)) in enumerate(itertools.izip_longest(fa, fb)):
            print(i, la, lb)
```

Should work.

On each iteration of the inner loop, `i` is the line number (0-indexed), `la` is the line from `fa` and `lb` is the line from `fb`.  If one file is longer than the other, either `la` or `lb` will be `None`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, you have just saved me a days work :)

Comment: @ScottPaterson fast answers are the name of the game around here -- gotta get that rep :)  Feel free to comment if you have any questions with how this turns out when you implement it.

Comment: hate to be a pain but i got through half the data and relised someone hasnt paid enough attention to the format :( basically splitting it off by characters [36:-10] wont work because not all of them have the same amount of characters. So i am trying to split it via rows. the problem im having is normally the code would read "for row in file(file): however i with this solution rather than saying row or line im using (1, a1, b1) and that wont work when it comes to splitting the data into rows. Any idea of a work around ?

Comment: @ScottPaterson When you say rows, do you mean columns?  Maybe columns delimited by something (whitespace, comma, semicolon, etc)?  I ask because usually the concept of rows == lines.

Comment: Good point yes i mean columns, Sorry I am really tired right now :)

Comment: Are the columns delimited by something?  Like maybe whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc)?

Comment: Sorry i should of specified i am using csv files so they are separated by a comma.

Comment: Well the simplest change would be to use something like `col_data = la.split(',')[col_num]` where `col_num` is the 0-indexed index of your column.  An alternative would be to change `with open('fileA.csv') as fa:` to something like `with csv.reader('fileA.csv') as fa:` after adding `import csv` at the top of your file.  If you went this route, you could access your columns the same way, but without split: `col_data = la[col_num]`.

Comment: ok using la.split(, ) i got it to work. Now the (hopefully) last problem is the way it actually sets the number. rather than setting it as 1234 it sets it as ('1234') and this cant be converted to a float or an Int which i would need to do math.

Comment: @ScottPaterson could you explain what you mean?  If you're getting `col_data` with split, it will be a string, if you want to convert it to an integer, you should be able to just use `col_data = int(col_data)` -- or whatever your variable name is.

Comment: ok here is my code http://pastebin.com/BdsgXBBY

It sets the data to a list in the format ['12345'] and because of the [''] parts it cant be converted to a string, float or int.

Comment: Never mind for some reason it wasnt letting me convert it out of a list. i managed to use list.join to convert it into a string which i can now conver out to a int.

But again, Thanks so much for your help you have been awesome :)

Answer (score -1):

use the module called "itertools.izip" to iterate over two iterables.

```
from itertools import izip
file1 = open("/var/tmp/a.txt")
file2 = open("/var/tmp/b.txt")
for line_a, line_b in izip(file1, file2):
    print "%s\t%s" % (line_a.rstrip(), line_b.rstrip())
```